# Address or reverse geocode a point shapefile

Tags: point, address, reverse-geocoding

I have a shapefile that contains points. I want to do a reverse geocode and give these points an address.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 6):

> Reverse Geocode (Geocoding)
>
> Creates addresses from point locations in a feature class. The reverse
>   geocoding process searches for the nearest address or intersection for
>   the point location based on the specified search distance.

In ArcMap, the tool is located under Geocoding Tools. Note that you'll need to have an address locator to reverse geocode with.

United States Street Address : http://gis.ats.ucla.edu/data/ESRI/9.3/Data%20and%20Maps%20and%20StreetMap%20North%20America/streetmap_na/data/US_AddressLocator.zip

Canada Address: http://gis.ats.ucla.edu/data/ESRI/9.3/Data%20and%20Maps%20and%20StreetMap%20North%20America/streetmap_na/data/Street_Addresses_CAN.loc

Bunch more if you browse the directory (look for .loc files): 
http://gis.ats.ucla.edu/data/ESRI/9.3/Data%20and%20Maps%20and%20StreetMap%20North%20America/streetmap_na/data/

Comment: Sometimes useful: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00250000002n000000.htm